# Write concise sbt configurations based on combinations of predefined configuration parameters

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm attempting to remove as much unnecessary strings from my `build.sbt` as possible

sbt offers way to use Provide, Test, etc. as configuration parameters, like so:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0" % Provided,
```

or

```
"org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.16.3" % Test,
```

But how can one rewite more complex configurations, like:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.3" % "test,it",
```

or

```
.dependsOn(util % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

Answer (score 3):

sbt is (bastardized) Scala code, so you can always write some functions or extension methods like:

```
def configs(head: Configuration, tail: Configuration*) =
  (head :: tail.toList).mkString(",")


implicit final class DependsOnProject(project: Project) {

  private val testConfigurations = Set("test", "fun", "it")
  private def findCompileAndTestConfigs(p: Project) =
      (p.configurations.map(_.name).toSet intersect testConfigurations) + "compile"

  private val thisProjectsConfigs = findCompileAndTestConfigs(project)
  private def generateDepsForProject(p: Project) =
      p % (thisProjectsConfigs intersect findCompileAndTestConfigs(p) map (c => s"$c->$c") mkString ";")

  def compileAndTestDependsOn(projects: Project*): Project =
    project dependsOn (projects.map(generateDepsForProject): _*)
}
```

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.3" % configs(Test, It)

projectA.compileAndTestDependsOn(util)
```

It's just an example, you can write your own utilities that suits your needs. You can also just assign these `String`s to `val`s and use named values instead.

Comment: Ah true of course. I just hoped there was this nice build in syntactic sugar, like `... % Test + IntegrationTest` or `% Compile -> Compile + Test -> Test`

Comment: sbt syntax is already confusing, and I am not sure if priority of operators would make something like that even less readable (e.g. `%` could bind before `->` or `+`), so I am kind of glad that they didn't make such utilities.